# Getting current information about Chrome app

Tags: google-chrome

On Windows 10, I have a number of web pages for which I used the "Add to desktop..." option in Chrome settings to have them start as 'applications' which I have pinned to the Taskbar:

[image]

[image]

When I say 'application', it's really just a separate Chrome window with no address bar or other browser-related identifiers, so it **feels** like its own application. But under the covers, it's just a Chrome browser window, really.

So now I can click on a link in my Taskbar and this opens as its own window, which I really like, since I use this for some work-related stand-alone stuff, which I want to keep separate from my other browser tabs:

[image]

However, if I navigate within this 'application' by clicking on links etc., since there is no address bar, is there any way to determine the URL of the **current** page? I can't right-click on the page

Comment: Right-click on the page works for me and gets me the context menu. You may use the extension [Copy page title and url](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-page-title-and-url/mcnddmglmjbomnfgkehnnblncllkaedm) to add an entry to this menu. Another way is by typing Ctrl-U to open a new browser tab with the url in its address bar.

Comment: @harrymc Like I said at the very end of my post, I can't use right-click (because the context menu has been overridden in JavaScript). And extensions don't seem to work in application windows. However, if you post this as an answer (not a comment), you'll get the bounty win, because I'd forgotten about View Source (Ctrl+U) which, whilst a hack, does indeed work.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to open a new browser tab with the
page-source and with, most importantly, the URL in its address bar.

If right-click on the page is not blocked in your application,
you may use the extension
[Copy page title and url](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-page-title-and-url/mcnddmglmjbomnfgkehnnblncllkaedm)
to add an entry to this menu that saves title and URL.

Answer (score 1):

In like harrymc's suggestion of viewing the source with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, here are a couple of other options (non-exhaustive):

- Hover over the link to see its address in the tooltip at the bottom of the window.
- Open the developer tools with <kbd>F12</kbd> (also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> should open a preview of what would be printed. If **Show headers and footers** is checked off, the URL will be added to the bottom of the printout (preview).